# Java SSLContext.init() hangs when called with OpenJDK 13 + 14 on Linux

Tags: java, linux, ssl

I have this small piece of code which is part of a larger application I am currently developing. When executed on Windows 10 with both OpenJDK 13 and 14 it works just fine. But when executed on Linux with OpenJDK 13 or 14 - the SSLContext.init() method just hangs. It *never* finishes. No exception, no error messages. Does anyone have a solution, or an idea about what could be wrong?

```
// SSSLContext for enabling Undertow server HTTPS
    SSLContext context;
    try{
        System.out.println("Keystore loading");
        var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(new File("./bin/keystore.pkcs12"), "123456".toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Keystore loaded");

        System.out.println("Creating KeyManagerFactory");
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        System.out.println("KeyManagerFactory created");

        System.out.println("Initializing SSLContext");
        System.out.println("Creating SecureRandom");
        SecureRandom instanceStrong = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        System.out.println("SecureRandom created");
        System.out.println("Creating SSLContext");
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        System.out.println("SSLContext created");
        **context.init(keyManagers, null, instanceStrong);**
        System.out.println("SSLContext KeyManagers set");
        System.out.println("SSLContext initialized");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error initializing SSLContext: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: The ** before and after the context.init(...) are not present in the real code. It was inserted by Stackoverflow when I tried to make that line bold.

Comment: I have tried with both Ubuntu 16.02, 18.04 and Fedora 31 . Same result.

Comment: In case it helps: See the notes for [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) - specifically: _Depending on the implementation, the generateSeed and nextBytes methods may block as entropy is being gathered, for example, if they need to read from /dev/random on various Unix-like operating systems._ Possible options to try: Use `urandom` - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html) or try starting the JVM with `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`.

Comment: I have now tried running with that -D command line option added, but the SSLContext.init() method call still blocks - forever. No messages, no exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I switched this line (in the code example above):

```
SecureRandom instanceStrong = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
```

To this line

```
SecureRandom instanceStrong = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNGNonBlocking");
```

And now I can get Undertow up and running on Linux too! Seems it *was* the blocking nature of SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong() that caused the problem.

Thanks a lot for suggesting where to look @andrewjames  !!

Comment: Nice! Never seen this before. I assume [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecureRandom) is where you looked to get the name?

Comment: Actually not, although I could have gotten it from there. I got it from some blog post somewhere after messing with the problem for a while. Just thought I'd share it once I found it.